# Use DataFrame values inside .loc[]

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, coding-style, computer-science

I want to filter a DataFrame in this way, base on dictionary values.

```
dict = { 
           101 : 2500,
           102 : 2700,
           103 : 2000,
}
```

And a DataFrame in this way:

| idx | match_id | type_name | second |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | Pass | 2400 |
| 2 | 101 | Shot | 2450 |
| 3 | 101 | Match_end | 2500 |
| 4 | 102 | Pass | 2700 |
| 5 | 102 | Match_end | 2600 |
| 6 | 103 | Match_end | 2000 |

I want a line of code that returns me the `match_id` values where `type_name==Match_end` and `second` is equal to the value inside the dictionary where the key has the same value of the match_id.

In this case I'd like to returns this list : [101,103]

Because, inside the DataFrame, the 3 and 6 rows respects the conditions (5 no because its `second` value is not the same of `dict.get(102)`).

I tried to use this code but without success because with `loc` I'm not able to use the relative index:

```
list = list(
           df.loc[
               (df["type_name"]=="Match_end")
               & (df["second"] == dict.get(df["match_id"]))
           ]["match_id"].values
       )
```

I need something inside the second condition which help me to use the dictionary based on `match_id` values of each row.

Does someone has some suggests to do this thing (with or without `loc`)?

`NB` I KNOW HOW TO DO THIS USING A FOR CICLE OVER "match_id" BUT I'M LOOKING FOR A METHOD TO DO THIS WITHOUT USE A FOR LOOP.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and compare by `second` column:

```
d = {  101 : 2500,102 : 2700, 103 : 2000}

print (df['match_id'].map(d))
0    2500
1    2500
2    2500
3    2700
4    2700
5    2000
Name: match_id, dtype: int64

L = df.loc[df['match_id'].map(d).eq(df['second']) & 
           (df["type_name"]=="Match_end"), 'match_id'].tolist()
print (L)
[101, 103]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make your dictionary as a dataframe (df1), you can manage by joining the dataframes with merge().

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'match_id':[101, 102, 103], 'second':[2500, 2700, 2000]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'match_id':[101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 103], 'type_name': ['Pass', 'Shot', 'Match_end', 'Pass', 'Match_end', 'Match_end'], 'second':[2400, 2450, 2500, 2700, 2600, 2000]})
```

Take only the rows from df2 where type_name == 'Match_end' as you are not interested of the others. Then drop that type_name column as it is not needed later.

```
df2 = df2.loc[df2.type_name == 'Match_end']
df2.drop('type_name', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Merge the two dataframes and you get the list that you want.

```
df = df1.merge(df2)
print(df.match_id.tolist())

[101, 103]
```